# C - How is the Null Pointer a constant?

Tags: c, pointers, constants

A constant is defined as **fixed values that cannot be altered by the program.** E.g. Direct values like `1, 2, 3, 'a'` and also defined constants like `#define CONSTANT 100`

So I was reading about the Null Pointer,

> The NULL pointer is a constant with a value of zero defined in several standard libraries.

But the pointer variable can be changed, proof:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int *a = NULL; /* Declaration\Definition of pointer and initialization of NULL */
    int b; /* Regular Declaration\Definition of variable */

    a = &b; /* pointer now stores memory address of b variable */

    return 0;
}
```

So if the Null Pointer is constant, then how come I compiled this with no errors.

and also before that I read.

> It is always a good practice to assign a NULL value to a pointer variable in case you do not have exact address to be assigned

So if the Null Pointer is constant, then when the case comes that we can grab the address we want, how could you assign it, constants cannot be altered.

Comment: **The `NULL`** pointer is constant. *A null* pointer is not necessarily constant. That quote is specifically talking about the macro `NULL`, which is a constant expression.

Comment: what about doing `double val = MATH_PI;` and then `val = 3.0;` ????  You have asigned a variable de value of a constant, and then you have assigned it another (different) constant.  The constant is the value, the variable is where you store that value.  Try this: `const double pi = 3.141592;` and then try to assign it a value (in this case pi is not a variable, it's a constant and the compiler doesn't allow you to change it's value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the same reason this works:

```
int x = 1;
x = 2;
```

You are *copying* a constant into a mutable variable, then mutating that variable. This doesn't affect the constant in any way, since it's a copy.

If you copy a book and then jot a note in the copy, does the original book have the same note?

Answer (score 4):

NULL is a constant.  Really and truly.
The location pointed to by  `a` is **not** a constant, and that is what you change here:

```
a = &b; /* pointer now stores memory address of b variable */
```

Answer (score 4):

`NULL` has a constant value, which you can assign to any variable. It does not mean that variable should be constant.

```
e.g. const int a = 2;
     int b = a;    // this statement is valid
```

Answer (score 3):

> The NULL pointer is a constant

This wording may be misleading (and pretty flawed, too) : `NULL` is a null-pointer constant. A `NULL` pointer is a pointer that points to `NULL`. You *can* chance a `NULL` pointer but you *can't* change what `NULL` expands to, namely a null-pointer *constant*.

```
int *ptr = NULL;
ptr = &variable; // ok

int *const ptr2 = NULL;
ptr2 = &variable; // fails: ptr2 is a const pointer

++NULL; // fails: expression not assignable
```

Answer (score 2):

```
int *a = NULL; /* Declaration\Definition of pointer and initialization of NULL */
```

Your comment has to change as follows and it will make it clear

> Declaration\Definition of pointer and initialization with NULL

NULL pointer means a pointer which don't have an address in memory, or a memory holding address  0 according to definition of NULL.

Answer (score 1):

This is tagged `C` but from a `C++` perspective, look at the the following code.

```
#include <iostream>

#define NULL 0
const int null = 0;

int main(){

    int var1 = NULL; //can do (copy NULL into var1)
    int var2 = null; //can do (copy null into var2)
    int &var3 = NULL; //can't do, NULL is not in memory so it can't be referenced
                      //same as doing int &var3 = 0
    const int &var4 = NULL; //can do, creates a constant reference for the value of NULL
                      // same as const int &var4 = 0
    int &var5 = null; //can't do, null is in memory thus can be referenced
                      //but the reference has to be a constant
    const int &var6 = null; //can do, references null with a constant reference 

    var1++; //can do
    var2++; // also can do
    var3++; //this is folly
    var4++; //can't do, it's a constant
    var5++; //this is also a folly
    var6++;  //can't do, it's a constant
    NULL++; //can't do NULL isn't a variable (lvalue), same as doing 0++
    null++; //can't do null is a constant

}
```

From  the code above, NULL isn't a constant variable but a constant expression. It is a macro. A macro is a constant expression that are processed in compile time.

> A macro is a fragment of code which has been given a name. Whenever
>   the name is used, it is replaced by the contents of the macro. There
>   are two kinds of macros. They differ mostly in what they look like
>   when they are used. Object-like macros resemble data objects when
>   used, function-like macros resemble function calls.

I an also do this `#define log std::cerr` but it doesn't make log a variable, although it does make it constant. Macros can be redefined like I did on `NULL` above.

On the other hand `null` is a constant **variable**. Any pointer or reference to it must also be constant to keep its immutability. But its value can be copied into another variable and that variable can be altered as done with `var2`.

Answer (score 0):

**The** (only) *null pointer value* actually is a constant: it is a specific, fixed value. IOW: There is only one value representing making a *pointer* a *null pointer*.

The macro `NULL` represents the *null pointer value*. The preprocessor will replace its name (like other macros) by the **textual** replacement. The text is then passed to the C compiler.

A *pointer variable* OTOH can be modified. It *can* be set to the *null pointer* value, making it a *null pointer*, but there is no problem in setting the *pointer* to another value. After this change, it is not **a** *null pointer* anymore.